# Lateral blur in digital images

Tags: focus, digital, blur, theory

I would like to know if is there any term or concept to refer to the effect of lateral blur of the objects which reflected rays enter the optic surface tangencially.

Is there any specific term for the case of digital cameras?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Reflected rays" from where, exactly? The intended subject? A surface inside the lens reflecting onto another element? Somewhere else?

Comment: @MichaelC maybe I have not used the correct concept. I refer simply to the rays reflected or reflexed by an object, which enter the eye or sensor and set the color of the object. My apologies if any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is called coma; where rays entering at an angle register offset.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've searched for this in Google and I think this is not what I'm searching, as this seeems to affect telescopes. My problem case is simply a RGB camera with a big vision angle, which some images seen to have the border pixels less clear than the center. 

I think about it like something similar to the camera focus, where the lens position is modified to center the capturing surface to chatch the specified rays.

Sorry if my vocabulary knowledge is not too specific.

Comment: This can affect any lens. It does affect camera lenses, and tends to affect the edges/periphery and wider FOV lenses most.

Comment: Okey, I see. In that case, if this also applies to cameras and digital lenses/sensors, this is the term. Thank you so much!!    (I can't vote your answer as I do not have enough reputation in this blog)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the classic optical aberrations affect edge and corner sharpness more than they affect sharpness at the center of the field:

Lateral chromatic aberration, Astigmatism, Coma, and Field Curvature all increasingly affect acutance in an image the greater the distance is from the center of the field.

Although Geometric Distortion does not affect acutance, [correcting for it with digital imaging certainly does](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2013/01/you-can-correct-it-in-post-but/), and affects the edges/corners of the field more than areas near the center.

Axial Chromatic aberration and Spherical aberration are the only two primary optical aberrations that affect all parts of the image field equally.

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, my case problem will not be the Axial Chromatic aberration nor the Spherical, but the Geometric Distortion, as it only affects my edges and corners of my images, is that right?

Comment: I could be Lateral Chromatic aberration, Astigmatism, Coma, Field Curvature, or Geometric distortion We can't tell you which it is because you haven't shown us any examples and your description is a bit unclear.